# Issue with Secure social in gmail Logout URL in play application

Tags: playframework-2.0, gmail, securesocial

I am logging in using secure social to log in into my application using gmail. I am facing issue in logging out from the gmail.

I am facing following error during my logout action.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=http://sample.domain.in:9020/googleLogout/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sample.domain.in:9020' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am calling following link in my application action to logout.

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=http://sample.domain.in:9020/googleLogout/
```

Please help me to sort this issue.

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding everything following the first `?continue=`

Comment: I didn't encode the URL. Because If I am copy pasting the https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=http://sample.domain.in:9020/googleLogout/ it is redirecting me to logout page. But from code I am facing this issue